# Magnetic energy evaluation

Tags: electromagnetism

How to evaluate magnetic energy when only vectors of magnetic induction **B**, and vector of magnetic field, **H** are known?

We know that in general,
$$W_m=\int w_mdV$$

where **wm** is the density of magnetic energy that is defined as
$$w_m=\int HdB$$

My question is, is it possible to evaluate magnetic energy **Wm** when only vectors **B,H** are known? If yes, what is the expression for magnetic energy in function of only **B,H**?

Answer (score 1):

If the relation between **H** and **B** is *linear* (whether the medium is isotropic or not), the energy density of the magnetic field is \$\tfrac{1}{2}\$**H⋅B**.

For a brief but unusual explanation, see § 2.2 of my [work in progress](https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3901935) (free download).